# How do I get the color from the backticks command in ruby?

Tags: ruby, console, rspec, terminal

In a ruby file:

When I do `system("rspec file_spec.rb")` I get a nice **colored output**.

When I do this:

```
result = `rspec file_spec.rb`
puts result
```

I get no color at all.

Is there any way to **preserve the color**?

btw, I'm on OSX with Terminal.app if that matters.

Comment: Does `rspec -c file_spec.rb` work? I would guess rspec is automatically turning off ANSI color codes because it can't check whether its output supports them.

Comment: I have `--color` in my rspec file in the rails app root, so the -c option does not matter.

Comment: I don't know how to preserve the color, but it not preserving it makes sense - most of the time, you wouldn't want to parse out the color information that comes from a `` command.

Comment: I think there's another question that asks something similar.

Comment: @Andrew -- yep, see my answer for the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From reading the code it looks like RSpec calls [IO#isatty](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000943) on the output stream to decide whether or not to colorize the output. The backquote method must work differently from `system` in this respect.

**EDIT**

This works if you add the option `--tty` to the rspec command:

`rspec --color --tty file_spec.rb`

as mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091296/how-to-enable-colors-with-rspec-when-using-jruby-or-bundle-exec).

Comment: Many commands have a --color or force color option if you are in a tty environment so check the man page!