# How to enable colors with rspec when using JRuby or bundle exec?

Tags: ruby, rake, jruby, rspec2

I'm trying to run my rspec's with JRuby:

```
rake spec
```

which results in:

```
jruby -S bundle exec rspec --color spec/foo_spec.rb
```

No colors show up, so I removed Jruby from the equation:

```
bundle exec rspec --color spec/foo_spec.rb
```

no colors. How can I get the "--color" option passed through to rspec? I've also got a .rspec file in the root directory of my project which doesn't seem to help in these cases. However, the .rspec file is picked-up or used when I just run:

```
rspec spec/foo_spec.rb
```

Any ideas?

Comment: weird. you're not running on windows, are you?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Adding `--tty` to the call fixes the problem for me:

```
jruby -S bundle exec rspec --tty --color spec/foo_spec.rb
```

The option tells RSpec that the output is not written to a file (in which case you wouldn't want colorized output), but send to another process instead.

Comment: what about rspec 1.*? there is no --tty option