# How do I keep the *colorized* output result of a command when printing the result of a command in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, terminal, colorize

Here's the thing:

I run a bunch of Cucumber tests from a ruby file by calling the command like this:

```rb
result = `bundle exec cucumber tests/specs/features`
[...] # do stuff with it
puts result
```

Now the result of the command has these nice colors telling me a lot about passing and failing tests by just looking at it without reading. But: when I put the result like this, the coloring is gone!

Is there any way of doing this without losing the coloring?

Comment: Have you trying forcing cucumber to use colors (using `--color` option)?

Comment: Yes! I found the same solution already, thanks. So this works:

`result = `bundle exec cucumber tests/specs/features --color --format progress``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078950/how-do-i-get-the-color-from-the-backticks-command-in-ruby) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091296/how-to-enable-colors-with-rspec-when-using-jruby-or-bundle-exec) questions, they are about just the same thing but with `rspec` instead of `cucumber`.